# Beamer frametitle: increase spacing for multi-lined titles

Tags: beamer, spacing, optional-arguments, frame-title

I am using a [custom beamer](https://github.com/lgienapp/leipzig-theme) theme and I am having an issue with long frametitles which occupy multiple lines. In that case, the title slides upwards, but I would prefer that it uses the space downwards:
[image: short Title work fine]
[image: long Titles use space on top of the title]

I'd like to keep the same spacing in both cases.
Wht are my options?

- Can I define an option `\frametitle[long]{longFrameTitle}` with a bigger separation?
- Can I write an if statement which increases spacing automatically if the title is longer than n chracters?
- Can I define something called `\longframetitle`?
- Can I insert spacing manually on each frame with long titles?

I am looking for the easiest solution, because it only is a problem in a few frames.

What I tried so far, but did not work:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[

    wd=\paperwidth,
    leftskip=1cm,
    rightskip=1cm,
    ht=5ex,dp=1.5ex
]{frame title}%
    \usebeamerfont{frame title}\insertframetitle%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{longframetitle}{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[
    sep=-7cm,
    wd=\paperwidth,
    leftskip=1cm,
    rightskip=1cm,
    ht=5ex,dp=1.5ex
    ]{frame title}%
    \usebeamerfont{frame title}\insertframetitle%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very dirt solution that seem to work is using the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\longframetitle}[2]{\frametitle{\tikz[inner xsep=0pt,baseline]{\node[anchor=base west] (titlePos) {\phantom{short fittitius title}};
\node[anchor=base west,text width=#1 ex] at (titlePos.base west) {#2};
}}}%\longframetitle{lenght of the line of the multiline title in ex}{title}
```

With your specific case:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{leipzig}
\begin{document}
\title{short Title}

\newcommand{\longframetitle}[2]{\frametitle{\tikz[inner xsep=0pt,baseline]{\node[anchor=base west] (titlePos) {\phantom{short fittitius title}};
\node[anchor=base west,text width=#1 ex] at (titlePos.base west) {#2};
}}}%\longframetitle{lenght in ex}{title} 

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{short Title}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\longframetitle{50}{Looooooooooooooooooong Title which\\[-2pt] occupies multiple lines}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: long frametitle on two line]